# Check table column and insert if value exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that has a column value in both but some are missing. I want to compare table 2 and insert a 1 if it is present, and 0 if it is not present in table 1. I am a newbie so , would appreciate some help on this.

Table 1:

```
custid  name   lastname  acc_exists
123456  eric   john
54658   david  peter
```

Table 2:

```
custid  name   order
54658   david  kl6545
65282   matt   pl5865
```

SQL:

```
INSERT INTO t1(acc_exists)  
SELECT UPPER(t1.custid)
FROM dbo.customer_accounts T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.customer_details t2
ON UPPER(t1.custid) = UPPER(t2.custid)
```

Comment: Are you using a case sensitive collation? If not, why the use of `UPPER` in the `ON`, other than to hinder performance?

Comment: yes some of the entries have lower case, and when I compare just making sure that the values match. does it matter? Like is it ok not to use upper? will it still match. For eg: 123456AB should match 123456ab

Comment: Also that SQL is very confusing. You have a table called `t1`, and then you alias a *different* table (`dbo.Customer_Accounts`) with the alias `t1`; meaning you have 2 different objects referenced as `t1` (one by name, the other by alias) within the same query... Though `t1` is a poor alias choice for a table called `customer_accounts`; `ca` would make more sense. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: *"yes some of the entries have lower case"* so are you saying "Yes, I am using a case sensitive collation."? If so, then I would suggest that `david` and `David` should not be treated as the same value, or you you should be ensuring that the values have the same case across your tables; applying `UPPER` to these columns in your `ON` and `WHERE` clauses will be terrible for performance.

Comment: If you *aren't* using a case sensitive collation, then the `UPPER` literally does nothing other than hinder performance; `'David' = 'DAVID' = 'david' = 'DaViD'` in a case insensitive collation.

Comment: got it, yes, I am using a case sensitive collation. Yes, my query is really bad, thats probably why I am not getting the desired output. any advice on how I can make that correct?

Comment: If you're in a `CASE` sensitive collation, then I suggest fixing your data; you should not be storing data that is meant to be the same value in different cases in different tables; they should be consistent. The point of a case sensitive collation is that `'David'` and `'david'` are intentionally **different** values.

Comment: gotcha. will do that. Yes, I agree it should be cleaned first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `INSERT` statement adds rows to a table. If you need to update column values of existing rows you need an `UPDATE` statement. If the "*customer_accounts*" table has no "*acc_exists*" field, you need to first alter the table to add that field:

```
ALTER TABLE customer_accounts ADD acc_exists2 INT;
```

Then you update values for this field by left joining between the two tables and assigning:

- `0`, when the "*customer_details*" table has NULL value
- `1`, otherwise

Given that you want to ignore case sensitivity in you join, you can cast the collation in the `ON` clause using `collate Latin1_General_CI_AS`:

```
UPDATE customer_accounts
SET acc_exists = CASE WHEN d.custid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM      customer_accounts a 
LEFT JOIN customer_details d
       ON a.custid collate Latin1_General_CI_AS = d.custid collate Latin1_General_CI_AS;
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=699e1d579d20ff2cafea052c6705390a).

Note: I'm assuming that the field "*custid*" uniquely identifies the single customer.

Comment: as the user states that he has a case sensitive collation, your query will not give the correct result.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. Updated solution and demo accordingly. @nbk